# Why pandas by themseleves convert int values in dataframe to float?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new here, ideally i would have commented this on the question from where i learned this usage of [idxmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149317/pandas-return-column-name-apply-function-for-each-row) :

I used same approach and below is my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4),columns=["A","B","C","D"],index=[0,1,2,3])
```

As soon as i use `df[(df>6)]` on this df these int values change to float?

```
        A   B   C   D
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN 7.0
2   8.0 9.0 10.0    11.0
3   12.0    13.0    14.0    15.0
```

Why does pandas do that? Also, i read somewhere i could use dtype=object on series , but are there some other ways to avoid such thing?

Comment: cause `np.nan` is float https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan

Comment: @Avij - not anymore, Optional Nullable Integer Support is now officially added on pandas 0.24.0 - finally :) - please find an updated answer bellow. [pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do want to have the int look like

```
df.astype(object).mask(df<=6)
Out[114]: 
     A    B    C    D
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN    7
2    8    9   10   11
3   12   13   14   15
```

You can looking for more information at [here](http://%20stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan), and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na)

***This trade-off is made largely for memory and performance reasons, and also so that the resulting Series continues to be “numeric”. One possibility is to use dtype=object arrays instead.***

More information about `astype(object)`

```
df.astype(object).mask(df<=6).applymap(type)
Out[115]: 
                 A                B                C                D
0  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>    <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 4):

The limitation is mostly with Numpy.

- Numpy's `ndarray` can only be of a single type.
- There does not exist an integer type null value.

So we end up with a dilemma when we do `df[df > 6]`.  What is going to happen is Pandas is going to return a dataframe with values equal to `df` where `df > 6` and null otherwise.  But like I said, there isn't an integer null value.  So we have a choice to make.

1. Use `None` or `np.nan` for null values while making the entire `ndarray` of `dtype==object`
2. Use `np.nan` as our null and make the entire array of `dtype==float`

Pandas chooses to make the arrays into float because keeping the values numeric will keep many of the advantages that come with numeric `dtypes` and their calculations.

---

**Option 1**
Use a fill value and `pd.DataFrame.where`

```
df.where(df > 6, -1)

    A   B   C   D
0  -1  -1  -1  -1
1  -1  -1  -1   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.DataFrame.stack` and `loc`
*By converting to a single dimension, we aren't forced to fill missing values in the rectangular grid with nulls.*

```
df.stack().loc[lambda x: x > 6]

1  D     7
2  A     8
   B     9
   C    10
   D    11
3  A    12
   B    13
   C    14
   D    15
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

In previous versions (<0.24.0) pandas indeed converted any int columns to floats, if even a single NaN was present. But not anymore, since Optional Nullable Integer Support is now officially added on pandas 0.24.0

[pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)
Quote: "**Pandas has gained the ability to hold integer dtypes with missing values.**